# jQuery AJAX ASync: False not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have searched and found a lot of answers to this question, but either the solutions did not work for me or I did not understand them, so [after 30 minutes I decided to ask for help](https://xkcd.com/627/).

I have a page where 3 syncs need to happen.  Each has a dedicated file to perform the server-side sync, and I have 3 functions in a row with the intention of them to cascade (order is important here) one after the other.

When I visit the page, however, it looks like all three start at the same time and end at the same time, so I suspect my `async: false` command is being ignored.  Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var spin = "<i class='blue fa fa-spinner faa-spin animated'></i>";
var complete = "<i class='green fa fa-check-circle-o'></i>";
var trouble = "<i class='yellow fa fa-times-circle-o'></i>";

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#teacher-status-icon").html(spin);
    jQuery("#teacher-status-text").html("Teachers - Syncing....");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./sync/teachers.php",
        success: function(result) {
            if(result == "done") {
                jQuery("#teacher-status-icon").html(complete);
                jQuery("#teacher-status-text").html("teachers - Complete");
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#teacher-status-icon").html(trouble);
                jQuery("#teacher-status-text").html("teachers - Complete with Errors");
            }
        },
        async: false
    });

    jQuery("#student-status-icon").html(spin);
    jQuery("#student-status-text").html("Students - Syncing....");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./sync/students.php",
        success: function(result) {
            if(result == "done") {
                jQuery("#student-status-icon").html(complete);
                jQuery("#student-status-text").html("students - Complete");
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#student-status-icon").html(trouble);
                jQuery("#student-status-text").html("students - Complete with Errors");
            }
        },
        async: false
    });

    jQuery("#classroom-status-icon").html(spin);
    jQuery("#classroom-status-text").html("Classrooms - Syncing....");
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./sync/classrooms.php",
        success: function(result) {
            if(result == "done") {
                jQuery("#classroom-status-icon").html(complete);
                jQuery("#classroom-status-text").html("classrooms - Complete");
            }
            else {
                jQuery("#classroom-status-icon").html(trouble);
                jQuery("#classroom-status-text").html("classrooms - Complete with Errors");
            }
        },
        async: false
    });

    jQuery("#next-button").removeClass("hidden");
});
</script>
```

I suspect I'm misunderstanding `async: false` but I'm not sure how.

Comment: just _daisy chain_ the ajax calls in the `success` callbacks. Put the second call in the `success` of the first, etc. and lose `async: false`

Comment: `async: false` is a terrible practice and is being deprecated by browser vendors. You should be seeing console warnings about using it

Comment: @WhiteHat It's ugly, but it works!  Thank you!  If you want to expand as an answer I'll select it.

Comment: will do, thanks! _ugly_ is why I didn't try in the first place...

Comment: it doesn't appear that the data from any of these calls is dependent on the others...correct? Just order is important?

Comment: @charlietfl Correct for the JS, but in the backend scripts order *is* important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*daisy chain* the ajax calls in the `success` callbacks.

Put the second call in the `success` of the first, etc...

and lose `async: false`...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var spin = "<i class='blue fa fa-spinner faa-spin animated'></i>";
var complete = "<i class='green fa fa-check-circle-o'></i>";
var trouble = "<i class='yellow fa fa-times-circle-o'></i>";

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    initCall("teacher", firstCallDone);

    jQuery("#next-button").removeClass("hidden");

    function initCall(item, callBack) {
        jQuery("#" + item + "-status-icon").html(spin);
        jQuery("#" + item + "-status-text").html(item + "s - Syncing....");
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "./sync/" + item + "s.php",
            success: callBack
        });
    }

    function getCallStatus(result, item) {
        if (result == "done") {
            jQuery("#" + item + "-status-icon").html(complete);
            jQuery("#" + item + "-status-text").html(item + "s - Complete");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            jQuery("#" + item + "-status-icon").html(trouble);
            jQuery("#" + item + "-status-text").html(item + "s - Complete with Errors");
            return false;
        }
    }

    function firstCallDone(result) {
        if (getCallStatus(result, "teacher")) {
            initCall("student", secondCallDone);
        }
    }

    function secondCallDone(result) {
        if (getCallStatus(result, "student")) {
            initCall("classroom", thirdCallDone);
        }
    }

    function thirdCallDone(result) {
        getCallStatus(result, "classroom");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: you could name your `success` functions, rather using anonymous, to clean it up some...

Comment: that looks like callback hell, definitely cleaner ways to do it

Answer (score 1):

Use the promise callbacks returned by `$.ajax` to avoid callback hell ( deeply nesting and indenting code). Each of the following `then` will commence after the prior ajax has completed so all will be in order.

Note that all ajax here is asynchronous ( `async:true`)

```
jQuery.ajax({
      url: "./sync/teachers.php",
      success: function(result) {
           // do stuff with teachers response
      }

}).then(function(){
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./sync/students.php",
        success: function(result) {
           // do stuff with students response
        }
     });
}).then(function(){
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: "./sync/classrooms.php",
        success: function(result) {
           // do stuff with classrooms response
        }
     });

}).then(function(){
   // all ajax is done now... do something here 
   jQuery("#next-button").removeClass("hidden");
});
```